# How do we prove the error estimation of the rectangle method

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, definite-integrals, estimation

Let $f\in C^2[a,b]$. An approximation of the integral over $[a,b]$ is given by $$I[f]:=\int_a^bf(x)\text{ dx}\approx \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf\left(a+\frac{i}{n}(b-a)\right)=:M_n[f]$$

I've spent a hard time trying to understand why it holds $$|I[f]-M_n[f]|\le \frac{(b-a)^3}{24n^2}\max_{x\in [a,b]}|f''(x)|$$ I would be deeply grateful if someone could explain this to me.

edit: rectangle rule shouldn't be (2i-1) or obviously 2n-1 would not exist

Comment: $24\,$ or $\,24n^2$ ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo - I'm sorry, you're right. It should be $n^2$.

Comment: The point is to prove that, on the k-th subinterval, one has $$|I_k[f]-M_k[f]|\le \frac{(b-a)^3}{24n^3}\max_{x\in [a,b]}|

f''(x)|$$Then sum over all subintervals and you are done.

Comment: why is it not i*(b-a)/n? this is not the rectangle method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we consider an interval symmetric with respect to zero $[-t,t]$.
We look for a bound of $$\left|\int_{-t}^t f(x)\,dx-f(0)\cdot 2t \right|$$
Let $$I(t)=\int_{-t}^t f(x)\,dx $$ Taylor's theorem says that $$I(t)=I(0)+I'(0)t+I''(0)\frac {t^2}{2!}+I'''(c)\frac {t^3}{3!}$$ where $0<|c|<t$ .

Now $$\begin {align}I'(t)&=f(t)+f(-t) \\ I''(t)&=f'(t)-f'(-t) \\ I'''(t)&=f''(t)+f''(-t) \end {align} $$ and so $$I(t)=2f(0)t+(f''(c)+f''(-c))\frac {t^3}{3!}$$Then $$|I(t)-2f(0)t|\le 2\max |f''|\frac {t^3}{3!}$$ Choose $\,t=(b-a)/2n\,$ and see the above comment to conclude.

Comment: Could you explain to me why the consideration of such an interval is without loss of generality? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I prefer to give you this [reference](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/2974788.pdf?&acceptTC=true&jpdConfirm=true), pp. 236-237

Comment: Using $[-t,t]$ in $M_1[f]$ yields $$\frac{t-(-t)}{1}f\left(-t+\frac{2-1}{1}(t-(-t)\right)=2tf(t)$$ So, shouldn't we look at a bound for $|I(t)-2tf(t)|$?

Comment: The midpoint of $[-t,t]$ is $0$

Comment: While that's right, how does it match the definition of $M_n[f]$?

Comment: The point is that your question contains a mistake: $$\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf\left(a+\frac{2i-1}{2n}(b-a)\right)$$ is exact.

Comment: why is it 2i-1? it shouldnt be if it is 2i-1, then what is a+(2n-1)*h itd be out of this interval

Comment: @jamesblack I don't understand your edits .... OP refers to the midpoint rule

Comment: right if its midpoint rule your right, but for rectangle it is such that $h*f_i$ right? h being $\frac {b-a} n$ f$f_i$ being f(a), f(a+h), f(a+2h).... which is f(a+i*(b-a)/n) how did you derive (2i-1)/2n*(b-a)? that is not the Rectangle rule --> Look at OP's title "how do ....RECTANGLE METHOD"

Comment: so either change the misleading title or change the midleading equation n i changed the latter

Comment: @jamesblack In my previous comment I advise the question has a mistake .... the symbol $M_n$ and the error bound show that OP refers to the midpoint rule ..... one should edit the title

Answer (score 1):

Use the Taylor's polynomial with error term.  $f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + f''(c)(x-a)^2/2$ where
$a \le c \le x$ (assuming $x >a$).

Comment: I'm sorry, I've updated my question. Your suggestion is helpful to prove $\le \frac{\cdots}{24}\cdots$, but I need $\le \frac{\cdots}{24n^2}\cdots$. Any idea for that too?